# Getting URL including parameters passed in an URL as a parameter

Tags: php

In my website I have a mechanism when your session has expired I save the current location and redirect you to the login page to log on, so the url is as follow

`localhost/mytest/admin/login-admin.html?current=localhost/mytest/admin/manage-customer.php?action=update&id_annonceur=2`

Once you are logged in, I redirect the user to the url stored in the current parameter.
The problem is when I use the following code

```
if(isset($_GET['current']))
    header('Location: http://'.$_GET['current']);
else
    header('Location: ../admin/dashboard.php');
```

I get the URL without the parameters included in the URL

```
http://localhost/mytest/admin/gestion-annonceur.php?action
```

Is there a way to retrieve the complete url including parameters?

Comment: use `urlencode` and `urldecode` when you set `$_GET['current']`

Comment: Your URL above is invalid. You shouldn't have two query strings (i.e. two `?`). You need to encode the url before passing it to the logon page using [`http_build_query()`](https://php.net/http_build_query) or some other appropriate method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you URL-encode the original URL when you put it into the `current` parameter. It should be:

```
localhost/mytest/admin/login-admin.html?current=localhost%2Fmytest%2Fadmin%2Fmanage-customer.php%3Faction%3Dupdate%26id_annonceur%3D2
```

Use the `urlencode()` PHP function to generate this encoding.